# Highcharts addPoint: Unable to get value of the property 'addPoint': object is null or undefined

Tags: html, highcharts

I wrote following code:

```
$(function instituciju_sprendimu_priemimo_palyginimas() {
var chart;    
$(document).ready(function () {     
    // Build the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container6',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Institucijų sprendimų priemimo statistika'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: ' ',
            data: []
        }]
    });
    chart.series[0].addPoint(['test1',100]);             
    chart.series[0].addPoint(['test2',200]);
});    
});
```

I got the following error:

> addPoint: Unable to get value of the property 'addPoint': object is
>   null or undefined.

I know, my question may be stupid, but I am just a newbie.

Comment: re-create your chart in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) and add link your question, then you will get answer faster.

Answer (score 2):

Take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/WyDH8/ which works well. Also I suggest to place addPoint function to callback Highcharts, then you will avoid null object.

http://jsfiddle.net/WyDH8/1/

```
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ 
       //parameter...
    },function(chart){

            chart.series[0].addPoint(['test1', 100]);
            chart.series[0].addPoint(['test2', 200]);

    });
```